# Is there a privilege in Oracle that lets a user view the objects in another schema?

Tags: oracle, permissions, access-control

Is there a privilege in Oracle that lets a user view or not view the list of objects in another schema?

I've got a user where I've given them select rights to a view in another user's schema. However, they don't seem to be able to see that view in their client (think they are using Oracle's SQL Developer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long and the short of it, there isn't a permission per se. ALL_TABLE and ALL_VIEWS will show you only the tables/views you have access to read from (as described by @Littlefoot).

I was presuming that Oracle might have a permission scheme like the Unix chmod 711 (rwx--x--x) - you can execute and work with files in the directory, but you can't list the contents of the directory.

In this particular case, the issue seems to have been Oracle SQL Developer and some form of caching.

Closing and reconnecting the Oracle connection in question did not refresh the changes in the access rights. However, shutting down the application completely and reopening did allow them to come through.

Evidently, the user in question hadn't restarted their application (or for that matter workstation) in sometime either.

A.K.A. Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a privilege, but a view - `all_tables` might help.

Connected as Scott, I'll grant `select` privilege to Mike:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL> grant select on dept to mike;

Grant succeeded.
```

Connect as Mike:

```
SQL> connect mike/xyz@orcl
Connected.

SQL> select table_name
  2  from all_tables
  3  where owner = 'SCOTT';      --> note OWNER

TABLE_NAME
------------------------------
DEPT

SQL>
```

If you omit `where` clause, you'll see all tables you have access to, but - it'll also show a lot of `SYS`, `SYSTEM` and similar users' owned tables, which is something you probably aren't interested in so - skip them, if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can give a try with below views:

You can query the `USER_SYS_PRIVS/ DBA_SYS_PRIVS` table with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT privilege FROM USER_SYS_PRIVS WHERE GRANTEE = 'username' AND PRIVILEGE = 'privilege_name';
```

To determine the object privileges granted to a user in Oracle, you can query the `ALL_TAB_PRIVS / USER_TAB_PRIVS/ DBA_TAB_PRIVS` table with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT privilege, table_name FROM ALL_TAB_PRIVS WHERE grantee = 'username';
```

Hope it helped !!

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a privilege in Oracle that lets a user view or not view the list of objects in another schema?

Oh, yes.  *Lots* of them.  :-)

> I've got a user where I've given them select rights to a view in another user's schema.

I'm guessing you're still at the "Users are important to Security" stage (Trust me; they're not).
I'd strongly suggest using *Roles* to confer privileges.  Then, when a given User moves on and someone comes in to replace them, you just grant them the Role and everybody's happy.  *Without* this, you'll probably have to try and rebuild all this from scratch (because you'll have *deleted* the first Users account, and all their privileges, when they left!)
Anyway ...

> However, they don't seem to be able to see that view in their client (think they are using Oracle's SQL Developer).

This might be as simple as they don't know *where to look* in that client!
Multiple schemas throws a lot of people when they start with Oracle.

When they fire up SQL Developer, they can see all the objects that *their account* owns.
To find objects owned by *any other* account, they have to rummage through the "tree" to find the "Other Users" entry, expand that, find the user in question and all the objects owned by *that* account (that they have privileges to see) will appear *there*.

```
+ Connection1
  + Tables
  + Views
    . . . 
  + Other Users   <-- This is the Trouble-maker  
    + User_2 
      + Tables
      + Views 
        . . . 
    + User_3 
      + Tables
      + Views 
        . . .
```

Comment: I'm guessing you are still at the "I have to be arrogant to show off how smart I am" stage of your career, and your manager has locked you in a room to keep the business safe from you and your attitude. I know I would with any of my team acting like you. However, you keep doing you.

Comment: Thanks!  I will.  But I strongly suspect I'll continue to get queries, just like this, from so-called "professional" Oracle Developers at least once a month, just as I do now.
The bit about Roles stands despite all that, though.